# Easy reading or transfer of data from posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, variables

Plugin usually transfer data using code like `[espro-slider id=21]` , is there a short way to read it or do they use regex to read it. If not is there a short way to define variable in post and use it directly in back-end. I am trying to read information from post and use it in page template to display custom code.

please help.

Comment: You can read those variable from shortcode callbacks without any regex. Please elaborate more what are you intended to do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`do_shortcode([espro-slider id=21])` will process the shortcode and return the result. [The Codex describes exactly this example](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode):

```
// Use shortcode in a PHP file (outside the post editor).
echo do_shortcode( '[gallery]' );
```

You can often just call the callback directly also:

```
function generic_shortcode_callback($atts,$content) {
  return "Yay! ".$content;
}
echo generic_shortcode_callback('',' Me!');
```

VS:

```
function generic_shortcode_callback($atts,$content) {
  return "Yay! ".$content;
}
add_shortcode('yay','generic_shortcode_callback');
$sc = do_shortcode('[yay]Me[/yay]');
echo $sc;
```